# VBA- search sheet name from range.. then copy from range sheet, paste transpose into that sheetname

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry. this is my last question for the day. I have been trying to find answers before I ask. and I appreciate all the help you guys give.

I have below Macro code.. My code limitation is that I have to type each word in range to search for it's matching sheetname.. However, I want vba to find sheetname from **each word** in range r2:r19 in sheet 'instructions' .. Copy that active cell row T:AE and transpose pastevalue into found sheet (CDH in this case) in range 'D4:D15'

```
Sub PasteBudget()
    Sheets("instructions").Select
    Columns("R2:R19").Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.Find(What:="CDH", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    'If Err.Number = 91 Then
        'MsgBox "ERROR: 'CDH' could not be found."
    '  End
    'End If

    Dim intRow As Integer
    intRow = ActiveCell.Row
    range("T" & intRow & ":AE" & intRow).Copy

    Sheets("CDH").Select
    range("D4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want without any errors:

```
Sub PasteBudget()
  Dim rng As Range
  With Sheets("instructions")
    Set rng = .Range("R2:R19").Find("CDH", , xlFormulas, 2, , 1, 0, , 0)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
      Intersect(rng.EntireRow, .Columns("T:AE")).Copy
      Sheets("CDH").Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , 1
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Following your edit this should do:

```
Sub PasteBudget()
  Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
  With Sheets("instructions")
    For Each sh In Worksheets
      Set rng = .Range("R2:R19").Find(sh.Name, , xlFormulas, 2, , 1, 0, , 0)
      If Not rng Is Nothing And sh.Name <> .Name Then
        Intersect(rng.EntireRow, .Columns("T:AE")).Copy
        sh.Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , 1
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dirk Reichel Thank you for help.. and my apologies.. I wasn't clear.. I want it to go through range r2:r19 and find each word related sheetname... also i am getting error at set rng line.

Comment: That worked !!!! omg you are life and time saver. the code didn't like 1 so i wrote True and False instead.. but other than that it is awesome. Thank you so so very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple code:

```
Dim sheetCDH as Worksheet
Set sheetCDH =ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDH ")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("instructions").Range("T" & intRow & ":AE" & intRow).Copy Destination:=sheetCDH .Cells(4, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you D T .. I do want it to transpose.